# Use Android Shared library (.so) files in Linux

Tags: ida, disassembly, linux, android

I decompiled an APK file,and that program have native codes in a `.so` file.

I want to use that `.so` file in Linux in order to use inline functions.
These codes have functions to connect to a server and perform encryption/decryption on the data transfered.

I decompiled that with IDA Pro too. Can I decompile and recompile ARM codes to a x64 CPU and run it in Linux ?

Or, do I need a light simulator to run that ARM `*.so` file ?

IDA Pro decompile the codes, I see the assembly functions but I'm not used to assembly, nor to reverse engineering. How to translates these functions to C or python functions ?

Comment: You need an emulator. There is an ARM VM here - http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroARM.html

Comment: You shouldn't use IDA anymore as Ghidra decompiles it a lot better to pure C code without any remainder in form of inline ARM and such. This enables you to recompile C code to x86-64 architecture or anything else you need. And there is no such language as x64, I don't know who started using this, the only language which exists is x86-64/IA64 which is just the same thing.

Comment: @Danil I converted your comment to a comment as it wasn't an answer. x64 is indeed _a thing_. In particular Microsoft was using that term for x86-64 early on as they supported AMD _and_ Intel CPUs. [Wikipedia even mentions x64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). Oh and sorry to break it to you, but x86-64 and [IA-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) **are not** the same thing ... and "IA64" is even less of _a thing_. x(86-)64 is a 64-bit extension of IA-32. So while your advice with Ghidra may be valid in general, _that_ wasn't available in 2015 to the public either.

Answer (score 6):

First, extract the whole APK (it's a renamed ZIP) and check whether there's not a x86 version of the binary, in addition of the ARM. It will depend on the best option to choose.

The following options assume that you have analyzed the binary using a tool such as IDA, Hex-Rays or Hopper and that you could identify the functions that you want to reach.

---

**If you need to emulate the calling conventions between a GLIB-based Linux system and a `.so` Android-targeted library, and that emulating the architecture is not a problem, for example because you have a x86 version of the library available in the APK:**

- One quite common, but sometimes painful option is using **[libhybris](https://github.com/libhybris/libhybris)**, a thin wrapper around Android's custom libc (Bionic) calling conventions that will allow you to call functions from the reverse engineered JNI from a regular GCC or Clang-compiled GLIBC program. Tutorials for libhybris are not numerous, but you'll find a couple of open source projects on the Internet that rely on it and will serve as sample code.

  However, libhybris will emulate the calling conventions but not the architecture.

---

**If you need to emulate both the architecture and the Android ABIs:**

- You have a few options here, either running your part of the program on an ARM host - this could be the Android emulator, your smartphone, a cheap ARM VPS, a Raspberry Pi or something else - either using an emulator such as [**QEMU in user mode**](http://nairobi-embedded.org/qemu_usermode.html) (that allows you to emulate a single ELF file in a chrooted environment without emulating a whole system). Also, you'll likely have to cross-compile your code.

---

**If you need to emulate the architecture, the Android ABIs and you wish to have more control over the emulated binary at the expense of parsing the ELF/handling the memory layout with code yourself:**

- Another option is using [**Unicorn engine**](http://www.unicorn-engine.org/), a library based on QEMU's code that allows you to emulate machine code on a foreign host in a way similar to using a debugger, by reading/writing registers, memory and setting breakpoints.

  Unicorn's API is pretty bare-metal: to use it, you parse the [**elf(5)**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) structure yourself, then, you allocate and write the relevant sections of the binary yourself, you set the registers (PC for the target function, SP at a point with free space, R0, R1 and so forth for the arguments, LR at a point where you set a hook) and your start the emulator.You can find a few easy-to-understand examples [here, in C and in Python](http://www.unicorn-engine.org/docs/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

For decompile a APK file, you can use different tools(https://mobilesecuritywiki.com/).
If you use python this is the best:

https://github.com/androguard/androguard or https://code.google.com/p/androguard/(see also this example: https://github.com/androguard/androguard/tree/master/demos)

You can decompile for ARM, but for test you should be use quemu (for ARM) or eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NativeFunction API of [frida](http://frida.re/). It helps you call any native function. With a little bit of reversing, you'll have something like

```
var func = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName('libxx.so', 'fun'), 'uint32', []);
```